# Grep a word and find its Count from log file for different times

Tags: python, shell, unix, count

log file which contains following data.

```
2014-10-19 17:30:25:
Creating destination directory: "\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\doc\" 
Loading source file Error \\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\JamesKohout.java... 
onstructing Javadoc information...Error
31 Error Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_26 Error
-encoding Error
19 windows-1252 
20 -charset Error
21 windows-1252 
22 -docletpath 
2014-10-19 18:30:25:
Creating destination directory: "\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\doc\" 
Loading source file Error \\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\JamesKohout.java... 
onstructing Javadoc Error information...
31 Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_26 Error
-encoding Error
19 windows-1252 
20 -charset Error
21 windows-1252 
22 -docletpath 
2014-10-19 19:30:25:
Creating destination directory: "\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\doc\" 
Loading source file Error \\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\JamesKohout.java... 
onstructing Javadoc information...Error
31 Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_26 Error
-encoding 
19 windows-1252 
20 -charset Error
21 windows-1252 
22 -docletpath 
2014-10-19 20:30:25:
Creating destination directory:Error "\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\doc\" 
Loading source file Error \\master1\users\jamesk\Java\chapter05\tech-support-complete\JamesKohout.java... 
onstructing Javadoc information...
31 Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_26 Error
-encoding Error
19 windows-1252 
20 -charset Error
21 windows-1252 Error
22 Error -docletpath
```

I want to write a script in Unix/python which greps the word "Error" and finds the wordcount of it from above log file at different times.
The file contains Data of Different time intevals.The word Error has a count 6 at the first time interval,the count at second time interval is 5 and so on.
I want the output as

```
2014-10-19 17:30:25:     Error Count=6
2014-10-19 18:30:25:     Error Count=5
2014-10-19 19:30:25:     Error Count=4
2014-10-19 20:30:25:     Error Count=7
```

I tried with the following command But it only gives the total word count present in the whole file.

```
grep -i "Error" | wc -l
```

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: so you're having trouble detecting the times?

Comment: Yes, I am not able to separately find the wordcount at diff times.

Comment: @Rohit check the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r"\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:|Error",re.IGNORECASE)
ll=pattern.findall(x)
d={}
for x in ll:
    if x!="Error":
        d[x]=0
        last=x
    else:
        d[last]=d[last]+1
print d
```

Here x is your data or file.read().

Comment: If I am correct, x is "".join(file.readlines()). But this works + 1

Answer (score 2):

Simple job with Awk.

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] [012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:/ {
       t=$0 }
    /Error/ { ++e[t] }
    END { for (s in e) print s "Error-Count=" e[s] }' logfile
```

Comment: awk is a beautiful language.

Answer (score 1):

A direct `awk`:

```
awk '/^201[0-9].*:/{if (cont){print cont}cont=0;printf $0}/Error/{cont+=1}END{print cont}' infile
```

Explained `code`:

```
awk '/^201[0-9].*:/{ # Timestamp pattern reached
                    if (cont){
                              print cont # print previus timestamp
                             }           # counter if exists and not zero
                    cont=0 # initialize actual timestamp counter 
                    printf $0
                   } #  print timestamp WITHOUT linebreak
            /Error/{ # Error patter reached
                    cont+=1 # Aaccumulated count
                   }
     END{
        print cont # print remainder counter
        }' infile
```

Comment: Prints any previous value of `cont`, prints the timestamp, starts collecting error counts into `cont` (which should perhaps be `count`?)

Answer (score 0):

here you go using python:

```
>>> f = open('logfile').readlines()
>>> i = 0
>>> while True:
...     if i+10 > len(f):
...        break
...     tmp = len(re.findall('Error',"".join(f[i+1:i+10])))
...     print f[i].strip() + " Error-Count=" + str(tmp)
...     i +=10
... 
2014-10-19 17:30:25: Error-Count=6
2014-10-19 18:30:25: Error-Count=5
2014-10-19 19:30:25: Error-Count=4
2014-10-19 20:30:25: Error-Count=7
```

Comment: What if the line count differs between the timestamps?