# Grep a word from log file for specific date and find its count for each hour

Tags: grep

I am having a data in a log file of following pattern

```
2014-11-21 14:33:25.8934 [224] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 14:35:20.8934 [224] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [224] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [224] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [219] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [219] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [219] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [219] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [219] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [161] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [161] IMP orange.at.banana - no error
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [161] IMP orange.at.banana - noerror
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [161] IMP orange.at.banana - error occurs this hour @KEY_VALUE_TYPE='
2014-11-21 15:37:25.8934 [161] IMP orange.at.banana - no error
```

I have such log files for different dates. I want to grep @KEY_VALUE_TYPE=' on differnents dates(eg.14-11-21,14-11-20) for every one hour and also want to find its count.

Please suggest some solution for doing this.

I tried using grep command and able to find count(but not on hourly basis) of @KEY_VALUE_TYPE=' for current date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep a word and find its Count from log file for different times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055408/grep-a-word-and-find-its-count-from-log-file-for-different-times)

Comment: Pipe the result of grey to  wc -l

Comment: Please suggest unix code for this

Answer (score 0):

```
cat logfile.log | grep "@KEY_VALUE_TYPE='" | sed "s/:.*$//g" | uniq -c
```

This:

1. Uses `grep` to find only the lines that you want
2. Uses `sed` to remove all of the detail from the line except date and hour. Basically it says match everything from the first colon to the end of the line and replace it with nothing.
3. Uses `uniq` to provide you the count of the occurances in each hour.

Output:

```
  2 2014-11-21 14
  9 2014-11-21 15
```

Note that `uniq` needs your data to be sorted, butas you're using a log file and counting based on the timestamp, it's already sorted.  Otherwise you could add a `sort` step before `uniq`

Comment: Thanks for solution.. 
`count date  time

2 2014-11-21 14 
9 2014-11-21 15 
19 2014-11-21 15` 

now if I want the sum of count of time 15 ie.(9+19=28)
How can I do this.

Comment: hi , I had to achieve some similar result , but the output is coming like below :
 128 2022-12-30 02
     26 2022-12-30 03
      1  at [Source
     61 2022-12-30 03
      1  at [Source
     15 2022-12-30 03
     50 2022-12-30 04
     54 2022-12-30 05
     29 2022-12-30 06
      1  at [Source
    175 2022-12-30 06
      1  at [Source
      1 2022-12-30 06
      1  at [Source
     28 2022-12-30 06
      1  at [Source
      3 2022-12-30 06
      1  at [Source
     
multiple records for same hour . 
command : zcat logfile.gz | grep "term" | sed "s/:.*$//g" | uniq -c